# How to combine and filter two dart Streams

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter_blue for a flutter Application using bluetooth.

flutter_blue presents me with two streams:
   FlutterBlue.instance.connectedDevices
   FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults

I would like to combine those two streams into one and apply a filter.

Googling around I get references to rxdart but still,, I cant get it to work.
Help please :)

Comment: [combineLatest2](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx/combineLatest2.html) ?

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want is `StreamGroup` from Dart's [async package](https://pub.dev/packages/async).

> The StreamGroup class merges a collection of streams into a single output stream.

It should be pretty easy, you just take your streams and use the `StreamGroup.merge(...)` method, passing the list of streams you want to merge. Take a look at this example:

```dart
import 'dart:async' show Stream;
import 'package:async/async.dart' show StreamGroup;

main() async {
  var s1 = stream(10);
  var s2 = stream(20);
  var s3 = StreamGroup.merge([s1, s2]);
  await for(int val in s3) {
    print(val);
  }
}

Stream<int> stream(int min) async* {
  int i = min;
  while(i < min + 3) {
    yield i++;
  }
}
```

which would print:

```dart
10
20
11
21
12
22
```

Once you have merged them, you can use standard `Stream` methods, such as `map(...)` to apply your filter in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rx.combineLatest2 like this:

```
class CombinedResult {
  final List<BluetoothDevice> connectedDevices;
  final List<ScanResult> scanResults;

  CombinedResult(this.connectedDevices, this.scanResults);
}

final filteredStream = Rx.combineLatest2<List<BluetoothDevice>, List<ScanResult>, CombinedResult>(
  FlutterBlue.instance.connectedDevices, 
  FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
  (devices, scanResults) => CombinedResult(connectedDevices, scanResults),
).where((combinedResult) {
  return true; //do your filtering here
});
```

Comment: Hi. I am not sure CombineResult is the correct function. At east, not as I understand its function.

Comment: Hi, CombinedResult is just a Wrapper class that i created to store the connectedDevices from the first stream and the scanResults from the second stream in a single object. In the filter function you could then access both with combinedResult.connectedDevices and combinedResult.scanResults to do your filtering.